# I did not make this purcase

Tags: security

I received an email yesterday that said APP Store Receipt.
Diamond Mobile Legends  Price $100     (5000 Diamonds)
I did not make this purchase.

Please cancel this or contact me for next step.

Comment: We are not Apple. You need to contact them to discuss this.

Answer (score 2):

We are not Apple, please see https://www.apple.com/contact/ for ways to contact Apple directly.

Before you do so, log into iTunes and check the purchase history there. The mail very much looks like spam, if the purchase doesn't show up in the purchase history you can safely ignore the mail.